# How Can I Send Custom Emails with Variables in .NET 6?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, mailkit, mailtrap

Hello I'm creating an API, I found how send emails using Mailkit with Mailtrap for testing purposes.
I share the code that I'm using:

```
public class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    public void SendEmail()
    {
        var email = new MimeMessage();
        email.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("", ""));
        email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(""));
        email.Subject = "Test Email";
        email.Body = new TextPart("plain")
        {
            Text = "Some Text"
        };
        
        using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Connect("", 2525, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
        smtp.Authenticate("", "");
        smtp.Send(email);
        smtp.Disconnect(true);
    }

}
```

So my biggest question it's if I wanna use the service that I made for every single email like verification email, reset password, etc. How can I add custom HTML in the body also use some variables if I want to send an email that says the username for example. At beginning I just thought save the body template in my database but If I wanna use some variables idk how can use it in that case.

**I hope that you can help with this silly thing haha given me some advice or tip!**

Comment: You can use custom html templates in MailKit to send out emails.

Comment: If you are ok with the templates being somewhat static, just create an EmailGenerator class or something. Add a method for each template and include the dynamic stuff as parameters. In each method, use StringBuilder, string interpolation, or similar to create the HTML output. Finally, use the BodyBuilder to let MailKit know that the content is HTML as shown here: http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Creating-Messages.htm

Comment: Services like SendGrid and many others allow you to set up parameterized templates, then you just supply the parameters when you want to send an email. Has the advantage of letting you tweak the layout / design at any time independently of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
email.Body = new TextPart("plain")
{
    Text = "Dear {ClientName},\r\nI am pleased to announce that you have won ${WinAmount}!!\r\n\r\nCongratulations!"
        .Replace("{ClientName}", "Bob")
        .Replace("{WinAmount}", "1,000,000")
};
```